# django admin how to get new object's id when overriding save_related

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the code below where I have modified the admin form to pass additional info which is then used after the save process is done.
This works fine when using the save button.
The problem with the code below is that when someone uses the "save as new" button, sample_pk would be the id of the current sample not the new sample that is generated.
My question is how to get the new object's id after calling the super on save_related.

```
@admin.register(Sample)
class SampleAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    save_as = True
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(SampleAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        args = request.resolver_match.args
        if len(args) < 1: # not previously saved
            return
        sample_pk = int(args[0])
        new_things = []
        for formset in formsets:
            for key, val in formset.data.items():
                if key.startswith('robo_'):
                    new_things.append(val)
        x = sum(new_things)
        sam = Sample.objects.get(pk=sample_pk)
        OtherTable.objects.create(x=x, sample=sam)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out. I should use:
**form.instance.id**

```
@admin.register(Sample)
class SampleAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    save_as = True
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(SampleAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        args = request.resolver_match.args
        if len(args) < 1: # not previously saved
            return
        sample_pk = form.instance.id
        new_things = []
        for formset in formsets:
            for key, val in formset.data.items():
                if key.startswith('robo_'):
                    new_things.append(val)
        x = sum(new_things)
        sam = Sample.objects.get(pk=sample_pk)
        OtherTable.objects.create(x=x, sample=sam)
```